# Exercises for strengthening foot twisting

Tags: strength, skiing

I have not found anything on this.

I want to strengthen muscles which help rotate the ski (i.e. point the skis left or right - for snow-plough turns and so on)

1. **What exercises would be best for this?** Preferably just using bodyweight.
2. **I assume the usual of 20-30 reps, but how often?**

I was thinking perhaps standing on one leg, and rotating my body left and right, but it sounds like it's asking for an injury!!

In case it matters, the reason I need this is when I had my last (beginners') ski lesson (3 hours) I just didn't have the strength to do snowploughing. I wasn't aching afterwards though which is weird.

Comment: Sit with your legs sticking straight out, feet in the air, with your ankles about a foot apart. Try to touch your toes together without moving them closer together. If your toes move towards each other, then you have enough strength to snowplow and its a technique issue. The amount of strength it takes to snowplow is negligible.

Answer (score 1):

If sticking to body weight exercises, I see your strategy as the best way to work the muscles you are aiming for. If you're willing to branch out into relatively basic equipment, resistance bands will allow for a less risky workout and better isolation of the muscle.

With the band, you could tie it around the bottom of a rack or something similarly sturdy, and then line up to the side of it, wrap the band around your foot, and work on twisting your foot away from the rack. This strategy would allow for you to be balanced while exercising, and also allow for a range of difficulty depending on how taut you make the band at the initial position.

For a lower impact exercise like this one, you could really do it every day if you wanted, to get into the routine of it, and a few sets of 20-30 reps should be good for the strength you are looking for. If you decide to use a band and are using a weaker one, you could always increase the reps, as while skiing this is a motion you conduct a lot.